# This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.5.0)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

When I copy my executable and lib dependencies to another computer and run the program I get this error:

> This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.5.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.

This error only happens in the new computer. I can run my program on my computer without any issue.

I tried to check with `ldd -d` and `objdump -p engine | grep NEEDED` which of the libs are that have protobuf in them, but I can't find them.

My program uses: opencv with Cuda, boost, tensorflow, tensorRT.

Both of the computer OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

How can I find which part has the issue with this conflict?

I tried to recompile opencv without protobuf by adding  `-DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DPROTOBUF_UPDATE_FILES=ON -DPROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include  -DPROTOBUF_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so`.

This did not solve the issue.

Comment: Do not copy binaries from one computer to another. You will have better luck if you recompile your executable on the new computer. Moving binaries can be done, but moving source files is *much* easier. And why are you recompiling OpenCV? Doesn't Ubuntu already provide it?

Comment: I have to copy all binaries, I can't recompile on another computer my program needs to be portable that way that I can "reinstall" it on any other computer

Comment: Binaries are generally not portable, source code is. You can only move your executable to the other computer if *all* the libraries it uses have compatible versions, and are compiled with compatible options. To make sure everything is the same version you can stuff everything in a container, and use that on the other machine. But as I said, recompiling is much easier, just run your build/install script (or Makefile) on your target machine. Because you do have such a script/Makefile don't you?

Comment: yes I have cmake for my project, but I do also need to download compile and install all the dependencies(boost, TensrRT, Tensorflw, opencv, ....) and that is what I want to avoid

Comment: I try to recompile all the code + dependencies on the new computer and still get the same error. what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @HAL9000 You really know nothing, Ubuntu does not provides opencv default, also, copy shared lib does not matter if they have dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different version `libprotobuf`, with one installed in `/usr/local/lib/` by dynamic library.

But when you build your program, you include other version of `libprotobuf`.

You can reinstall `libprotobuf` to solve this question.

If you install `libprotobuf` from source, make sure you added the flag `-Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`.

Comment: exucse me i checked and found `libprotoc10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.so.10
libprotoc10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.so.10.0.0` . which i should remove and how can i re-install libprotobuf ?